# Import tool Excel CSV

Tags: jquery, mysql, csv, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

I need an import tools for a web app.  I've been looking around and found some, just not sure about their stability.  I'm using the Zend Framework for part of the project and was hoping I could find an import tool there, since I already have the framework, but couldn't see one...am I looking in the wrong place?

I would like the web users to be able to import csv, excel files into a mysql database.  I'd like the tool to allow the users to select the columns of the spreadsheet/csv to match up to the database columns if possible.  For the exporting side I'm leaning to using jasper reports to export a dataset to csv,excel...is this a good/bad idea?

Are there some tools free or commercial tools that you have used and would recommend, to allow me to incorporate this feature into my website?

Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be very similiar to [8031193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031193)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For import:**
Try MySql's built-in csv import: [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourdata.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**For export:**
Try the jQuery plugin: [table2csv](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php). It converts an HTML table into a CSV file. Use the argument, delivery:'value', to return the csv as a string.

Here's an [example implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196695/export-html-table-to-excel/2197665#2197665).  I know it's in C#, but there's only a little code involved. It would be easy to port to PHP.

Comment: Wow, that guy should make a table2XML plug-in.